# Is "late by an hour" grammatical?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

For example, I need to be at a place at 7:00, but got there at 8:00. Can I say "I got there late by an hour"? I know a more commonly used expression is "I was an hour late", but for now I only want to know whether the one I suggested is correct.

Comment: The sentence is not OK if the question mark was there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've already mentioned, it's not common, but I think it's OK grammatically. [Ref.](https://www.quora.com/Which-one-is-correct-I-will-be-late-for-half-an-hour-as-guests-have-come-to-my-house-or-I-will-be-late-for-a-half-hour-as-guests-have-come-to-my-house-Why-is-that-correct)

I would add a comma to make it clearer:

> I got there late, by an hour.

Comment: The reason why I don't want to use "I was an hour late" is that I want to keep the verb "got". So is there a common expression for this which keeps the verb (apart from the one with the comma)?

Comment: "I got there an hour late"